# Graph API SDK v5 Batch request is not setting the request body

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I just started updating my code to use Graph API v5 SDK from Graph API v3 SDK. One of the methods is used to create Users in bulk, so I am using Batch functionality to accomplish this.

The issue I am having is that after creating thousands of users successfully I am getting throttled (429 - TooManyRequests) which is expected given the number of requests I am sending for testing. So I just wait before trying to send the failed requests again. I recreate the `BatchRequestContent` and the steps for the failed requests, however the problem is that it seems the request content is not being set to the `BatchRequestSteps`.

I am getting this response for every individual requests in the batch request:

```
{
    "error":
    {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "A value is required for property 'displayName' of resource 'User'.",
        "innerError":
        {
            "date": "2023-04-20T21:00:51",
            "request-id": "cc4ff088-eadd-4c67-841b-33e13cf55705",
            "client-request-id": "e1750988-e9a9-42f9-8872-0db64f17118a"
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at fiddler, before getting throttled, the batch request body looks fine:

```
 {
    "requests":
    [
        {
            "id": "3fe67305-1340-4126-b634-cc6da3d6cad7",
            "url": "/users",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers":
            {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer token...",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body":
            {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                "accountEnabled": true,
                "displayName": "user 4501",
                "mailNickname": "user4501",
                "onPremisesImmutableId": "123",
                "passwordProfile":
                {
                    "password": "123"
                },
                "usageLocation": "US",
                "userPrincipalName": "user4501@tenantdomain.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        }
        ...
```

But afterwards it looks like this:

```
{
    "requests":
    [
        {
            "id": "981a22a7-9d99-4397-a31b-82ef2b18b78c",
            "url": "/users",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers":
            {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer token",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body":
            {}
        },
        {
            "id": "db799eb1-6050-4c4f-a276-3e5f96fa53bb",
            "url": "/users",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers":
            {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer token",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body":
            {}
        }
```

The code creating the successful requests and the retry-requests is pretty much the same.

This is the code I create to reproduce the issue:

I am using:

- NET 6
- Microsoft.Graph 5.7.0
- Azure.Identity 1.8.2

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;

namespace GraphAPIUpdate
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var clientId = "";
            var clientSecret = "";
            var tenantId = "";
            var cc = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(cc);

            List<User> users = new List<User>();
            var prefix = "1";
            var tenantName = "";
            for (int i = 1; i <= 20000; i++)
            {
                var user = new User
                {
                    DisplayName = $"{prefix}user {i}",
                    AccountEnabled = true,
                    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile { Password = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() },
                    MailNickname = $"{prefix}user{i}",
                    UsageLocation = "US",
                    UserPrincipalName = $"{prefix}user{i}@{tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com",
                    OnPremisesImmutableId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                };

                users.Add(user);
            }

            Dictionary<string, User> usersDictionary = new Dictionary<string, User>();

            foreach (var userChunk in users.Chunk(20))
            {
                var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent(graphClient);
                foreach (var user in userChunk)
                {
                    var postRequest = graphClient.Users.ToPostRequestInformation(user);
                    var requestId = await batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStepAsync(postRequest);
                    usersDictionary.Add(requestId, user);
                }

                var batchResponse = await graphClient.Batch.PostAsync(batchRequestContent);
                var responses = await batchResponse.GetResponsesAsync();
                var failedResponses = responses.Where(r => !r.Value.IsSuccessStatusCode).ToList();
                if (failedResponses.Any(x => x.Value.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests))
                {
                    await Task.Delay(160000);

                    var retryBatchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent(graphClient);
                    foreach (var failedResponse in failedResponses)
                    {
                        var user = usersDictionary[failedResponse.Key];
                        var postRequest = graphClient.Users.ToPostRequestInformation(user);
                        await retryBatchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStepAsync(postRequest);
                        Console.WriteLine($"{failedResponse.Key} - {user.DisplayName}");
                    }

                    var retryBatchResponse = await graphClient.Batch.PostAsync(retryBatchRequestContent);
                    var retryResponses = await retryBatchResponse.GetResponsesAsync();
                    foreach (var response in retryResponses)
                    {
                        var c = await response.Value.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue seems to be that the object that is passed to the `ToPostRequestInformation(user)` method cannot be reused to create the subsequent retry POST request.

As I mentioned I noticed the issue when resubmitting the requests after getting throttled but this can be easily reproduced using a single object, submitting the same object on different BatchRequestContents one after another.

```
var user = new User()....
var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent(graphClient);
var postRequest = graphClient.Users.ToPostRequestInformation(user);
var requestId = await batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStepAsync(postRequest);
var batchResponse = await graphClient.Batch.PostAsync(batchRequestContent);
var responses = await batchResponse.GetResponsesAsync(); // 201 - Created

batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent(graphClient);
postRequest = graphClient.Users.ToPostRequestInformation(user);
requestId = await batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStepAsync(postRequest);
batchResponse = await graphClient.Batch.PostAsync(batchRequestContent);
responses = await batchResponse.GetResponsesAsync(); // 400 - Bad Request
```

First requests looks fine:

```
{
    "requests":
    [
        {
            "id": "998a9fab-5349-428b-99bf-229515b1f110",
            "url": "/users",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers":
            {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer toekn...",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body":
            {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                "accountEnabled": true,
                "displayName": "test 1",
                "mailNickname": "test1",
                "onPremisesImmutableId": "1",
                "passwordProfile":
                {
                    "password": "1"
                },
                "usageLocation": "US",
                "userPrincipalName": "test1@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Second request has an empty body:

```
{
    "requests":
    [
        {
            "id": "717b13a9-be38-4c34-a3fc-262ecc892ced",
            "url": "/users",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers":
            {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer token...",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body":
            {}
        }
    ]
}
```

The workaround I found is to clone the user object and use that in the second request, then the request body is properly set;
And I get the expected result for this scenario as the user has been created already.

```
{
    "responses":
    [
        {
            "id": "42eb46d4-da3d-436d-8277-09253f8f4076",
            "status": 400,
            "headers":
            {
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                "x-ms-resource-unit": "1",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body":
            {
                "error":
                {
                    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
                    "message": "Another object with the same value for property userPrincipalName already exists.",
                    "details":
                    [
                        {
                            "code": "ObjectConflict",
                            "message": "Another object with the same value for property userPrincipalName already exists.",
                            "target": "userPrincipalName"
                        }
                    ],
                    "innerError":
                    {
                        "date": "2023-04-21T17:13:12",
                        "request-id": "752bfab6-a5ba-4e68-bb98-e2bedc35b029",
                        "client-request-id": "31ca97d2-47ef-41b2-b5f9-c6d93c4df8cd"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What is the proper solution to avoid this issue?